# Enabled Add-In Does Not Persist beyond Session

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint Add-In (**"Chart Builder"**) which when enabled manually (Developer | Add-Ins | Add New) the add-in persists in the Application beyond the session expiration. I.e., I can close PowerPoint, reopen it later, and then the Add-In is still "installed" and available to use.

For ease of distributing updates, I have created another Add-In (**"Controller"**) which checks the version for updates, and installs the most recent version if necessary on user machines.

The **Controller** calls this from the ribbon `onLoad` callback:

```
Option Private Module
Option Explicit
Private rib As IRibbonUI
''Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

    Set rib = ribbon
    Call UPDATE(rib)
End Sub
Private Sub UPDATE(rib)

'Debug.Print ObjPtr(rib)

'1 Check for valid network connection:
    If NetworkConnected Then
'2 Check the add-in already exists:
        If Not AddInExists Then
            If Not DoUpdate Then Exit Sub
        End If
'3 Call procedure to update the PPAM if needed
        If CheckUpdate Then
            Application.Run "ChartBuilder_PPT!AddIn_RibbonExtensibility.RibbonOnLoad", rib

        Else:
            MsgBox "unable to enable the CB ribbon!", vbCritical
        End If

    Else
'4 The user is not connected to the network
Debug.Print "Not connected to JDPA network."

    End If

End Sub
```

So we check if connected to network (pass) then we check if the Add In already exists, if not then we prompt for update.  Then if yes, then **Controller** downloads the current version from a shared directory path and activates/installs on the user machine.

The problem is that when this add-in is installed, it is *always* taking me to the `DoUpdate` function (which prompts the user `vbYesNo` to update the version).

That function is reproduced below, and `ShortName` is a public Const representing the ShortName of the **Chart Builder** add-in.

```
Function AddInExists() As Boolean
Dim a As AddIn
    For Each a In Application.AddIns
        If a.Name = ShortName Then
            AddInExists = True

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**QUESTION**

Is there some property of the Add-In that I need to set when activating it (I do `.Loaded = msoCTrue`?

Or are the Add-Ins loaded sequentially, such that *when* **Controller** is loaded, **Chart Builder** is not (yet) and this triggers false negative on the `AddInExists()` function?  And if this is the case, is there anything I can do to change the *order* of load, or otherwise prevent this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well that didn't take long to figure out during my normal troubleshooting/debugging. Posting the answer in case it is helpful to others.

> Is there some property of the Add-In that I need to set when activating it (I do .Loaded = msoCTrue?

Yes. Ensure the `.AutoLoad = msoCTrue`.